# Assignment operator (=) and returning values in Perl

Tags: perl

In Perl the assignment operator `=` returns the value that was assigned.

`$a = 5` means, as far as I know:

Set `$a` to the value of `5` and return `5`.

Now:

If I have something like this:

```
$a = 5 + ($b = 2);
```

If I assume that the assignment operator does not return `2` it would read like this, wouldn't it:

`$a = 5 + $b;`  and Perl could happily say that the solution is `7`.

But that's not the way it works. Why not? Am I missing something?

Why has the assignment operator have to return the value of `2`? Isn't there already enough information to do the addition even without returning the number `2`?

To me it sounds like overcomplicating things.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get across. `$a = 5 + ($b = 2)` first evaluates `$b = 2`, then calculates `$a = 5 + $b`. It is true that this could in theory be constant-folded to `scalar($b = 2, $a = 7)`, but that's to complicated to be useful. So what exactly is your issue?

Comment: If you look up in wikipedia it says: "The basic assignment operator is "=" which sets the value on the left side to be equal to the value on the right side. It also returns the value." http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Operators#Assignment So it does two things: Assigning and returning. What you wrote is pefectly obvious to me from an "only assignment perspective" but it does more. It is also returning and that baffles me because to me it seems totally uneccessary.

Comment: Let's imagine a theoretical world where `=` always returns -1. Then `$a = 5 + ($b = 2);` means the same as `$b = 2; $a = 5 + -1;` which means that `$a` is now -4. That world sucks. But we're not in that world, because `=` returns something sensible. Yay for `=`!

Answer (score 1):

The assignment returns the assigned value. While this shouldn't be in my opinion used to write code like `$a = 5 + ($b = 2);`, it's helpful when you have multiple variables with the same value.

```
$blah = $more_blah = 0;
```

If `$more_blah` wouldn't return its value (`0` in this case), `$blah` wouldn't get the proper return value.

Comment: Yes. But why does it return the assigned value? Why is that neccessary? That's my question. To me it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @user3542317: This is because `$blah =` gets `$more_blah = 0` as an argument. If it wouldn't, it wouldn't get the same value as `$more_blah`.

Comment: Re "The assignment returns the assigned value.", Actually, it [returns](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) the LHS (`$b`), not the assigned value. (`perl -E'$_ = 5 for scalar( $x = 4 ); say $x'`)